# Adding/removing listeners to array in actionscript3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, button, for-loop, output

Good morning!

I'm currently working on a project of making a hangman game. And I use animated buttons instead of the keyboard to output the different letters in the game. But the biggest and only problem I've encountered is the fact that the buttons will not be recognized as the value they outuput. If I trace array[i] in the "addButtonListeners" function all I get for every single button is "[object SimpleButton]". Every button in the animation is named A,B,C and so on.

Now I want to ask you. Do you have a soloution my problem, or a different soloution. I've added the necessary code you need. The inactive variable is working fine. The problem there is that the inactive objects won't be placed correctly due to the buttons not being recognized. Thanks in advance!

```
    var inactive:Inactive;//Blocks buttons already pressed
    var icontainer:Array = new Array();//Array to save inactive buttons for easy removal 
    var keys:int = 0;//Count buttons that are inactive, this indicates how many "icontainer" that must be deleted. 
    var index:int;//Saves the value of String.search method, used to search after button pressed
    var buttons:Array;//Array with all the buttons


    buttons = new Array(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,Æ,Ø,Å);


function init(e:MouseEvent)
{ 
    addButtonListeners(buttons);//Adds listeners to the buttons 
    ...
}


function addButtonListeners(array:Array):void
{   
    for (var i:int = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
    {
    array[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onKeyPress);
    }
}


function removeButtonListeners(array:Array):void 
{   
    for (var i:int = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
    {
    array[i].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onKeyPress);
    }
}

function onKeyPress(e:MouseEvent):void 
{ 
    /* Gets and deactivates button */ 

    inactive = new Inactive();
    inactive.X = e.currentTarget.parent.X;//Added "parent" because flash recognizes the MC inside as "name"
    inactive.Y = e.currentTarget.parent.Y;

    addChild(inactive); 
    icontainer.push(inactive); 
    keys++; 

    /* Plays sound */ 

    btnSnd.play(); 

    /* Check if letter is in the word */ 

    index = currentWords.search(new String(e.currentTarget.parent.name)); 

    if (index != -1) 
    { 
        /* Letter is in the word */

        for (var i:int = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
        { 
            if (new String(e.target.parent.name) == letters[i]) 
            { 
                tfs[i].text = new String(e.target.parent.name); 

                correctLetters++; 
            } 
        }

        if (correctLetters + spaces == letters.length)//If word is complete 
        {
            win(); 
            removeButtonListeners(buttons); 
        }
    }
    else 
    { 
        tries--; 

        switch (tries)//Shows the hangman parts
        { 
            case 6 : 
            trace(6);
            break;

            case 5 :
            head.visible = true; 
            break;

            case 4 :
            body.visible = true;
            break;

            case 3 :
            leftArm.visible = true; 
            break;

            case 2 :
            rightArm.visible = true; 
            break;

            case 1 :
            leftLeg.visible = true; 
            break;

            case 0 :
            rightLeg.visible = true;
            for (var j:int = 0; j < letters.length; j++)//Shows the missing parts
            { 
                if (tfs[j].length == 0) 
                {
                    tfs[j].textColor = 0xFF0000; 
                    tfs[j].text = letters[j]; 
                }
            }

           removeButtonListeners(buttons); 
           fail();
           break;

           default :
           trace("Error"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your onKeyPress function?

Comment: A,B,C,... are actual instances or instance names?

Comment: Calling `array[i]` will only return a reference to your buttons as their class, in this case `SimpleButton`. The variable names in your code (A, B, C and so forth) is just for your (and somewhat the compiler's) convenience. I'd suggest writing a custom class that extends the `SimpleButton` class, and give that a custom param, e.g. `letter` that describes the letter for each button instance.

Comment: why you are using e.currentTarget in some places and e.target in some other places? any particular reason?

Comment: A,B,C... are actual instrances.
You sure that will do it. stalem? 
I was just testing if that was the difference. Haven't changed it after apparently.